# Cordova/PhoneGap - pass app store validation

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

Ive just finished up my first Cordova/PhoneGap app but it was rejected on submission to the App Store on grounds that it was too much like a website. But PhoneGap apps are very much like websites in that they are all coded in HTML and CSS, so how do you get round this issue? Has anyone had this rejection notice before and overcome it?

(I am using a couple of iframes in the app - could this be a contributor to the issue? Should I replace the information they display with data retrieved via JSON?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Too much like a website" likely doesn't refer to the technology used, but the content enclosed. If your app is essentially what you'd get if you went to a mobile version of your website, Apple would prefer you just build a mobile version.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you but I feel that the app offers more than what a website can do. Do you know if there is a way to contact (call) the review board so I can discuss this more directly?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewboard/index.html but I wouldn't count on much different of an answer.